# Stuck on a Python Zybook Challenge Problem

Tags: python

Prompt: Complete Creation (3.20)

Copy your solution from Creation (3.20) to here but delete the print statements (I PASTED THIS BELOW)

Make an empty list. The list will be used to store Student namedtuples

Add Kenneth and Maegan to the list

Create a funtion makeStudent(studentlist) where studentlist is your list of Student namedtuples

The function should do the following:
Take user input for each of the fields of the namedtuple
Create a Student namedtuple using the input
Add the Student to studentlist

Call makeStudent 3 times

Print student_list

### Print Students whose list positions are odd in student_list

Hello! Can anyone help clarify what to do for step 5(Lab 3.2.1). The instructions are very ambiguous and unclear

1. Copy posted my code from 3.2.0

2.Deleted my print statements

3/4: #made an empty list and added "Kenneth" and "Maegan" to the list. Let me know if this is wrong and if the prompt is actually telling me to directly insert the names into the list.

```
student_list = list()
student_list.append('Kenneth')
student_list.append('Maegan')
```

5. Really confused about what to do. No hints were given either. I tried to do a def makeStudent(studentlist):
   but was really confused about how I should write out the rest of the function. I experimented with doing a single line as well to gain all the inputs.

The function should do the following:
Take user input for each of the fields of the namedtuple (I tried doing it line by line input, and even one line)
Create a Student namedtuple using the input(How would I paste my input in the namedtuple? Same one as the one in code 3.20?)
Add the Student to studentlist(student_list.append(Student or 'Student'))
then I guess do that 3x. Use of return function.

print student_list

Then do List Sequence Slicing, I assume: lst[:] for example
My code is below

```
  from collections import namedtuple
    Student = namedtuple("Student", ["name","major","year","id","gpa"])
    Student1 = Student("Kenneth", major="Computer Science", year=6, id=987654321, gpa=3.8)
    Student2 = Student("Maegan", major="Neuroscience", year=4, id=123456789, gpa=3.4)

    # make list
    student_list = list()
    student_list.append('Kenneth')
    student_list.append('Maegan')
    # add Kenneth and Maegan to the list


    # make function
    # print list / list with odd names
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understood, it's asking you to do the following. However, in the final part, I didn't see where it was asking for odd numbered names, so I just printed out the whole list.

```
from collections import namedtuple
Student = namedtuple("Student", ["name","major","year","id","gpa"])
Student1 = Student("Kenneth", major="Computer Science", year=6, id=987654321, gpa=3.8)
Student2 = Student("Maegan", major="Neuroscience", year=4, id=123456789, gpa=3.4)

# make list
student_list = list()

# add Kenneth and Maegan to the list
student_list.append(Student1)
student_list.append(Student2)

# make function
def makeStudent(studentlist):
    name = input("Enter name: ")
    major = input("Enter major: ")
    year = input("Enter year: ")
    id_ = input("Enter id: ")
    gpa = input("Enter gpa: ")
    new_student = Student(name, major=major, year=year, id=id_, gpa=gpa)
    studentlist.append(new_student)

# call makeStudent 3 times
for _ in range(3):
    makeStudent(student_list)

# print list
print(student_list)
```

When you run the script, if you enter the following values:

```
Enter name: John
Enter major: EE
Enter year: 1999
Enter id: 123
Enter gpa: 4
Enter name: Pete
Enter major: CS
Enter year: 2000
Enter id: 234
Enter gpa: 3
Enter name: Sam
Enter major: IE
Enter year: 2001
Enter id: 345
Enter gpa: 2
```

the final list would be printed out like so:

```
[Student(name='Kenneth', major='Computer Science', year=6, id=987654321, gpa=3.8),
Student(name='Maegan', major='Neuroscience', year=4, id=123456789, gpa=3.4),
Student(name='John', major='EE', year='1999', id='123', gpa='4'),
Student(name='Pete', major='CS', year='2000', id='234', gpa='3'),
Student(name='Sam', major='IE', year='2001', id='345', gpa='2')]
```